# JSON parsing using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse a JSON object using GSON.

My JSON is :

```
{ "truncate": [
            {
                "lower": 20,
                "upper": 40,
                "delimiter": " ",
                "scope": ["$title"]
            },
            {
                "lower": 30,
                "upper": 65,
                "delimiter": " "
            }
        ] }
```

I have defined my 2 classes like:

```
public class TruncateObj {

    private List<TruncateObjectChild> objChild;

    // getter and setter
}
```

and

```
public class TruncateObjectChild {

    private int lower;

    private int upper;

    private String delimiter;

    private List<String> scope;

// getters and setters
}
```

My Parsing statement is

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();   
 TruncateObj truncation = gson.fromJson(template, TruncateObj.class);
```

For some reason this is not working. Gson creates a `TruncatObj` child, but the `List<TruncateObjectChild>` within the TruncateObj is null.

What is wrong in what I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `objChild` in your `TruncateObj` does not match the name it has in the JSON.  Rename the field to `truncate` and try again.

Alternatively, you could annotate the `objChild` field with an `@SerializedName("truncate")` to tell gson to use the value from the `truncate` field in the JSON as the value for the `objChild` field in your Java object.