# Using Enums while parsing JSON with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

This is related to a previous question that I asked here earlier

[JSON parsing using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207274/json-parsing-using-gson/8207343#8207343)

I am trying to parse the same JSON, but now I have changed my classes a little bit.

```
{
    "lower": 20,
    "upper": 40,
    "delimiter": " ",
    "scope": ["${title}"]
}
```

My class now looks like:

```
public class TruncateElement {

   private int lower;
   private int upper;
   private String delimiter;
   private List<AttributeScope> scope;

   // getters and setters
}


public enum AttributeScope {

    TITLE("${title}"),
    DESCRIPTION("${description}"),

    private String scope;

    AttributeScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public String getScope() {
        return this.scope;
    }
}
```

This code throws an exception,

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer EnumTypeAdapter failed to deserialized json object "${title}" given the type class com.amazon.seo.attribute.template.parse.data.AttributeScope
at
```

The exception is understandable, because as per the solution to my previous question, GSON is expecting the Enum objects to be actually be created as

```
${title}("${title}"),
${description}("${description}");
```

But since this is syntactically impossible, what are the recommended solutions, workarounds?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From [the documentation for Gson](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/Gson.html):

> Gson provides default serialization and deserialization for Enums... If you would prefer to change the default representation, you can do so by registering a type adapter through GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Type, Object).

Following is one such approach.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(AttributeScope.class, new AttributeScopeDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    TruncateElement element = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), TruncateElement.class);

    System.out.println(element.lower);
    System.out.println(element.upper);
    System.out.println(element.delimiter);
    System.out.println(element.scope.get(0));
  }
}

class AttributeScopeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<AttributeScope>
{
  @Override
  public AttributeScope deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException
  {
    AttributeScope[] scopes = AttributeScope.values();
    for (AttributeScope scope : scopes)
    {
      if (scope.scope.equals(json.getAsString()))
        return scope;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class TruncateElement
{
  int lower;
  int upper;
  String delimiter;
  List<AttributeScope> scope;
}

enum AttributeScope
{
  TITLE("${title}"), DESCRIPTION("${description}");

  String scope;

  AttributeScope(String scope)
  {
    this.scope = scope;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 372):

I want to expand a bit NAZIK/user2724653 answer (for my case). Here is a Java code:

```
public class Item {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private Status currentState = null;

    // other fields, getters, setters, constructor and other code...

    public enum Status {
        @SerializedName("0")
        BUY,
        @SerializedName("1")
        DOWNLOAD,
        @SerializedName("2")
        DOWNLOADING,
        @SerializedName("3")
        OPEN
     }
}
```

in the json file you have just a field `"status": "N",`, where N=0,1,2,3 - depend on the Status values. So that's all, `GSON` works fine with the values for the nested `enum` class. In my case i've parsed a list of `Items` from `json` array:

```
List<Item> items = new Gson().<List<Item>>fromJson(json,
                                          new TypeToken<List<Item>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: This answer solves everything perfectly, no need for type adapters!

Comment: When I do this, with Retrofit/Gson, the SerializedName of enum values has extra quotation marks added. The server actually receives ```"1"```, for example, instead of simply ```1```...

Comment: What will happen, if json with status 5 will arrive?
Is there any way to define default value?

Comment: @DmitryBorodin If the value from JSON does not match any `SerializedName` then the enum will default to `null`. Default behavior of unknown state could be handled in a wrapper class. If you however need a representation for "unknown"  other than `null` then you will need to write a custom deserializer or type adapter.

Answer (score 38):

Use annotation `@SerializedName`:

```
@SerializedName("${title}")
TITLE,
@SerializedName("${description}")
DESCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 15):

The following snippet removes the need for explicit `Gson.registerTypeAdapter(...)`, using the `@JsonAdapter(class)` annotation, available since Gson 2.3 (see comment [pm_labs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275800/pm-labs)).

```
@JsonAdapter(Level.Serializer.class)
public enum Level {
    WTF(0),
    ERROR(1),
    WARNING(2),
    INFO(3),
    DEBUG(4),
    VERBOSE(5);

    int levelCode;

    Level(int levelCode) {
        this.levelCode = levelCode;
    }

    static Level getLevelByCode(int levelCode) {
        for (Level level : values())
            if (level.levelCode == levelCode) return level;
        return INFO;
    }

    static class Serializer implements JsonSerializer<Level>, JsonDeserializer<Level> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Level src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return context.serialize(src.levelCode);
        }

        @Override
        public Level deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            try {
                return getLevelByCode(json.getAsNumber().intValue());
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                return INFO;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this annotation is only available starting version 2.3: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/index.html?com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html

Comment: be careful to add your serializer/deserializer-classes to your proguard config, as they might be removed (it happened for me)

Comment: I get and error: @JsonAdapter value must be TypeAdapter or TypeAdapterFactory reference. gson v2.5

Answer (score 10):

With GSON version 2.2.2 enum will be marshalled and unmarshalled easily.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

enum AttributeScope
{
  @SerializedName("${title}")
  TITLE("${title}"),

  @SerializedName("${description}")
  DESCRIPTION("${description}");

  private String scope;

  AttributeScope(String scope)
  {
    this.scope = scope;
  }

  public String getScope() {
    return scope;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use the Enum's ordinal value you can register a type adapter factory to override Gson's default factory.

```
public class EnumTypeAdapter <T extends Enum<T>> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
    private final Map<Integer, T> nameToConstant = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<T, Integer> constantToName = new HashMap<>();

    public EnumTypeAdapter(Class<T> classOfT) {
        for (T constant : classOfT.getEnumConstants()) {
            Integer name = constant.ordinal();
            nameToConstant.put(name, constant);
            constantToName.put(constant, name);
        }
    }
    @Override public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        return nameToConstant.get(in.nextInt());
    }

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        out.value(value == null ? null : constantToName.get(value));
    }

    public static final TypeAdapterFactory ENUM_FACTORY = new TypeAdapterFactory() {
        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
        @Override public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
            Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
            if (!Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType) || rawType == Enum.class) {
                return null;
            }
            if (!rawType.isEnum()) {
                rawType = rawType.getSuperclass(); // handle anonymous subclasses
            }
            return (TypeAdapter<T>) new EnumTypeAdapter(rawType);
        }
    };
}
```

Then just register the factory.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
               .registerTypeAdapterFactory(EnumTypeAdapter.ENUM_FACTORY)
               .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
GsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: as of gson 2.8.5 this is required in order to use SerializedName annotations on enums that you want to use as keys