# Custom deserialization of enum using GSON

Tags: java, enums, customization, deserialization, gson

I need to make the following json:

```
[ { "contentType": "folder" },
  { "contentType": "image" },
  { "contentType": "video" }
]
```

Parse in such array:

```
FileStructureElement [] elements[];
```

Having:

```
public class FileStructureElement {
    private ElementType contentType;
}

public enum ElementType {
    FOLDER, IMAGE, VIDEO, DEFAULT;
}
```

This is simplified example, `FileStructureElement` class has many more properties, irrelevant for the question fields.

I want to load the values of `contentType` property as values of `ElementType`. I can not afford making the values of the enum match the types of the json, because one of the possible values in the json is "default", which is not a valid enum value. Furthermore, I would like to not have enum values with lowercase names. This basically means I need customization of the GSON parsing. Can somebody help me with that?

The idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211304/using-enums-while-parsing-json-with-gson) (checking the values of the property i parse and choosing upon it whether to load enum value or not), does not help me because I have no control of the web service interface I talk to and the values are too obvious and I risk that they will also be present as values of some of the other json atttributes.

Comment: you should give your classes definition

Comment: @user1488644 Thank you for the constructive comment. I have simplified further and modified my question. Hopefully now you will be able to help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a custom parsing for the enum, you need to register an adapter

```
JsonDeserializer<?> jd = new JsonDeserializer<ElementType>() {
  @Override
  public ElementType deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    String enumStr = json.getAsString();
    ElementType val = 
    //...

    return val;
  }
};

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ElementType.class, jd).create();
```

Just return the right enum value for the provided String.