# What can be a sample JSON payload for my object structure?

Tags: java, json

I'm new to JSON hence the answer to my question would be a huge help!

I have an enum like below:

```
enum Error
{
    private final String message; 

    INVALID("failed"),
    VALID("succeeded");

    Error(String message){
       this.message = message;
    }

}
```

And my class is like:

```
class Response {
    String id;
    Error error;
}
```

How do I create a sample JSON payload for this?

Comment: I don't know java - but usually it's a value of enum underlying type  like {"id":"someId", "error":"enum_value_here"}

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate and serialize you class using Gson, you will get a JSON string that is the exactly payload you are looking for.

For example, if you execute this:

```
 Response r = new Response();
 r.id="AA";
 r.error = Error.INVALID;

 Gson defaultGson = new Gson();
 System.out.println(defaultGson.toJson(r));
```

you will get

```
{"id":"AA","error":"INVALID"}
```

Of course, you could use alternative way to serialize/deserialize your enum like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19715374/1360888)