# Serializing a map of enums with Gson with custom serialization

Tags: java, enums, gson

Following suggestions in [Using Enums while parsing JSON with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8211304/2083907), I am trying to serialize a map whose keys are an `enum` using Gson.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Main {

    public enum Enum { @SerializedName("bar") foo }

    private static Gson gson = new Gson();

    private static void printSerialized(Object o) {
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(o));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSerialized(Enum.foo); // prints "bar"

        List<Enum> list = Arrays.asList(Enum.foo);
        printSerialized(list);    // prints ["bar"]

        Map<Enum, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(Enum.foo, true);
        printSerialized(map);    // prints {"foo":true}
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1. Why does `printSerialized(map)` print `{"foo":true}` instead of `{"bar":true}`?
2. How can I get it to print `{"bar":true}`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gson uses a dedicated serializer for `Map` keys. This, by default, use the `toString()` of the object that's about to be used as a key. For `enum` types, that's basically the name of the `enum` constant. `@SerializedName`, by default for `enum` types, will only be used when serialized the `enum` as a JSON value (other than a pair name).

Use `GsonBuilder#enableComplexMapKeySerialization` to build your `Gson` instance.

```
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
```