# How to store in HashMap a JSON with Gson

Tags: android, json, hashmap

Team i need a right way to store data into a `HashMap<>` using Gson coz i´m doing as the follow Java class but when i try to get some value from the `HashMap<>` i just get `NullPointerException` Error, i succesfull get the Json to Java class coz when i try to get some value out of the `Hashmap<>`, Why i need to store it in `HashMap<>` thats coz the Objects names are very  random and i can´t make a class for each item.

Java class where i try to store the JSON  data:

```
public class Response {

private int id;
private String name;
private UserBean user;
private List<ItemsBean> items;

public int getId() {return id;}

public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

public String getName() {return name;}

public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public UserBean getUser() {return user;}

public void setUser(UserBean user) {this.user = user;}

public List<ItemsBean> getItems() {return items;}

public void setItems(List<ItemsBean> items) {this.items = items;}


public static class UserBean {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

}


public static class ItemsBean {

    private HashMap<String, CodecBean> codec;

    public HashMap<String, CodecBean> getCodec() {return codec;}

    public void setCodec(HashMap<String, CodecBean> codec) {this.codec = codec;}

    public static class CodecBean {

        private int id;
        private int strong;
        private boolean active;
        private String sell;

        public int getId() {return id;}

        public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

        public int getStrong() {return strong;}

        public void setStrong(int strong) {this.strong = strong;}

        public boolean isActive() {return active;}

        public void setActive(boolean active) {this.active = active;}

        public String getSell() {return sell;}

        public void setSell(String sell) {this.sell = sell;}
    }
}}
```

JSON:

```
{
"id": 1001,
"name": "Super1",
"user": {
    "name": "The Super 1"
},
"items": [{
    "987987M7812b163eryrt": {
        "id": 1,
        "strong": 456,
        "active": true,
        "sell": "te"
    },
    "90812bn120893juuh": {
        "id": 2,
        "strong": 4700,
        "active": true,
        "sell": "tt"
    },
    "981273jn19203nj123rg": {
        "id": 3,
        "strong": 3000,
        "active": true,
        "sell": "ti"
    }
}]
}
```

I try to get values as this way:

```
Response.ItemsBean item = (Response.ItemsBean) getItem(i);
TextView txt;
txt.setText(item.getCodec().get(i).getSell());
```

Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have been flagged ... it will be nice ban ...

Comment: do you want to save data ?

Comment: @Nasimxon yes i need to save the "items" in HashMap

Comment: @Selvin why you say that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32149138/1827254

Answer (score -1):

I think you need use LinkedTreeMap instead of Hashmap
change follow code

```
....
private LinkedTreeMap<String, CodecBean> codec;
...
```

Comment: i made the classes like that and the same result, `NullPointerException`