# GSON deserialise a string attribute to an object

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

I have a Json response of the following type -

```
{
    userName:"Jon Doe",
    country:"Australia"
}
```

My User class looks like this -

```
public class User{
    private String userName;
    private Country country;
}
```

GSON parsing fails with the following error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 3 column 18 path
>   $[0].country

Is there any way to tell GSON to parse country into the Country object with my current JSON response?

Comment: [tried this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18483355/1398531)

Comment: What is Country? A class or an enum?

Comment: @roby Country is a class.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Thank you for the link. Let me go through it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by registering a custom deserializer.

```
public static class Country {
    private String name;

    public Country(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
    }
}

public static class Holder {

    private String x;
    private Country y;

    public Holder() {
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(Country y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Holder{" + "x='" + x + '\'' + ", y=" + y + '}';
    }
}


@Test
public void test() {
    GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
    gson.registerTypeAdapter(Country.class, (JsonDeserializer) (json, typeOfT, context) -> {
        if (!json.isJsonPrimitive() || !json.getAsJsonPrimitive().isString()) {
            throw new JsonParseException("I only parse strings");
        }
        return new Country(json.getAsString());
    });
    Holder holder = gson.create().fromJson("{'x':'a','y':'New Zealand'}", Holder.class);
    //prints Holder{x='a', y=Country{name='New Zealand'}}
    System.out.println(holder);
}
```