# How to create a model that implemest parcelable

Tags: android, model, parcelable

My response is like below

```
"data":[
    {
        "title": "hbdv",
        "description" : [
             "a", "b", "c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "bdvv",
        "description": [
             "d", "f"
        ]
    }
]
```

I created a custom model say X

then

```
@SerializedName("title") String a;
@SerializedName("description") ???
```

How to create model that implement `parcelable`.

Comment: show what you already done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Enums while parsing JSON with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211304/using-enums-while-parsing-json-with-gson)

Comment: refer this [link]( https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8634-robopojogenerator) its android studio plug in for create model

Answer (score 0):

create your model and implement it with Parcelable
then you need to generate some methods
1- Constructor with parcel input parameter
2- Creator
3- override describeContents method
4- finally override writeToParcel method

for example

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


    public class yourClass implements Parcelable{
    private String title;
    private String[] description;

    private yourClass(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
        description = in.createStringArray();
    }

    public static final Creator<yourClass> CREATOR = new Creator<yourClass>() {
        @Override
        public yourClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new yourClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public yourClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new yourClass[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(title);
        parcel.writeStringArray(description);
    }
}
```