# How to convert a string from Retrofit to a custom object in my data class model?

Tags: android, object, kotlin, type-conversion, retrofit

I am receiving a Category object from Retrofit:

```
    data class Category(
       val id: Int,
       val title: String,
       val type: CategoryType
    )
    data class CategoryList(
       @SerializedName("categories")
       val categories: List<Category>
    )
```

where CategoryType is an enum class:

```
enum class CategoryType constructor(
    var title: String
) {
    CAT_CHICKEN("chicken"),
    CAT_PORK("pork"),
    CAT_STEAK("steak"),

    companion object {
        fun getCategoryTypeByName(text: String): CategoryType? {
            return when (text) {
                "chicken" -> CAT_CHICKEN
                "pork" -> CAT_PORK
                "steak" -> CAT_STEAK
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My api call is like this:

```
@GET("categs/melist/")
suspend fun getCategories(): Response<CategoryList>
```

How can I convert the 'type' variable that comes from the server as a string to a CategoryType object?

Comment: Your question is basically "How to convert the JSON response into my enum". This was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18851314/990129

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Enums while parsing JSON with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211304/using-enums-while-parsing-json-with-gson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is what your categories (for example "steak") doesn't match your enum values (for example CAT_STEAK). Use @SerializedName keyword:

```
enum class CategoryType constructor(var title: String) {
    @SerializedName("chicken")
    CAT_CHICKEN("chicken"),
    @SerializedName("pork")
    CAT_PORK("pork"),
    @SerializedName("steak")
    CAT_STEAK("steak"),

    companion object {
        fun getCategoryTypeByName(text: String): CategoryType? {
            return when (text) {
                "chicken" -> CAT_CHICKEN
                "pork" -> CAT_PORK
                "steak" -> CAT_STEAK
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea it's that simple. Retrofit in a good library. It worked and fixed all my issues. Thanks